# Stop notifyDataSetChanged() to focus on an element

Tags: java, android

I have a listview and I am loading data into the listview from arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
When I click on the Fragment, I get scrolled down to the place where the ListView is there, rather than just opening the Fragment.

I have already tried to put this on a runnable which doesn't work.
Also tried .requestFocus() which didn't work either.

I expect the Fragment to just present without scrolling down and focusing on a ListView.

```
    nameRef.child(currentSub).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      try {
          sub.add(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString());
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

  }
});
```

Comment: Could you share some relevant code?

Comment: done, the above is the following where I set the adapter Notify Data Changed